# Is this an instance of the knapsack problem?

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

I have what seems like a simple problem, but I'm struggling to solve it. Turning to Google it appears this may be a variation of the Knapsack problem, but I'm having trouble mapping those solutions to this particular problem.

Let's say I have two lists of positive integers, A and B. I want to find the value that represents the largest common sum between these two lists.

```
A: [6, 1]
B: [5, 3, 1]
```

Here, the answer is 6, because that's the largest sum that can be created commonly in both lists (by removing the 1 in list A and removing the 3 in list B).

I can naively solve this in O(2^n) but I'm assuming there's a much more efficient approach via dynamic programming, though dp is not my strength.

Is this the knapsack problem? Any pointers as to how I should map the classic knapsack problem to this two-list problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved in `O(nW)`, where `n` is count of all elements and `W` is a sum of all elements in lists.

Process each list separately. Let `dp1[i][j]` be true if there is a subset of the first `i` elements of the first list, which sum is equal to `j` (`0 <= i <= n1`, `0 <= j <= W1`). `dp1` can be filled using recurrent formula:

- `dp1[0][0]` is `true`
- `dp1[0][j]` is `false` (`j != 0`)
- **EDIT**: `dp1[i][0]` is **`true`** (`i != 0`)
- `dp1[i][j]` is `true` if:

  - (`j >= list.get(i)` AND `dp[i - 1][j - list.get(i)]` is `true`)
  - OR `dp[i - 1][j]` is `true`

Then fill `dp2[i][j]` for the second list. Then just find the maximum number `S` for which both `dp1[n1][S]` and `dp2[n2][S]` are `true`.

Comment: Wow, thank you @ardenit. Out of curiosity, is this a variant of the knapsack problem?

Comment: Well, this solution is very similar to solution of subset sum problem, so it may be counted as a variation of knapsack problem.

Comment: this could be an implementation error on my part, but I believe your algorithm doesn't allow for taking an item from one of the lists without taking all preceding items. In my original question, if I had reordered list A, i.e. A: [1, 6], the answer should still be 6. But with your solution, there is no way to obtain a value of 6 from list A (since taking the 2nd element assumes you're also taking the 1st element).

Comment: Are you sure that you implemented this line -> `OR dp[i - 1][j] is true`

Comment: Yes, I implemented that line. I'm struggling with understanding what the meaning of `dp[i][j]` is -- originally, I assumed it meant a value of true for i, j indicated a value of j could be achieved by taking i elements from the list. But I no longer think that's what dp represents. If you apply your algorithm to List=[1, 6] what is your resulting dp?

Comment: The only way for `dp[i - 1][6]` to be true for that list is for the previous check, `dp[i - 1][j - list.get(i)]` to populate `true`. And since 6 is the second element in the list (`i == 2`), `dp[1][0]` is not `true`

Comment: You misunderstand what `dp` means. As I said, `dp[i][j]` is true if there is a subset (any subset, of any size) of the first `i` elements of list, with sum `j`.

Comment: Ah, there is a stupid mistake in my algorithm, I fixed it. Although it was about one of base cases (`j = 0`), not about the algorithm itself. For your example, `dp[2][6]` is `true` because `dp[1][0]` is `true`.

Comment: And `list.get(i)` in this algorithm means "get i-th element of the list" (`list.get(1)` returns the first element)

Comment: Ahh ironically I was questioning whether that should be `true` and not `false` but I couldn't put my finger on why that would work. But makes sense now.